# select2 show default value in multiple select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I use https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple
I use loading data to options:

```
  var data = [
  {  id: 0, text: 'Hawaii' },
  {  id: 1, text: 'California' },
  {  id: 2, text: 'Bla' }
];
```

and set default values:

```
$basicMultiple.val(["0", "1"]);
```

when I load page and click on field, it look like this: 
[image]

Hawaii and California selected

Than, if i click on Bla option, field look like this:

[image]

how to make default values visible in field right away page loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the selected values without notifying Select2 that you've made changes. So while Select2 can tell that you have made two selections when you open the dropdown, it didn't know that when it was rendering the selections.

You can tell Select2 that you've made changes by triggering the `change` event on the original `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

you most set `tags` property to true to show like you want on initiation, like this code

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$basicMultiple.val(["0", "1"]).trigger("change");`